# PCA on a heterogenous correlation matrix better than MCA?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, pca, multivariate-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I have a questionnaire of 80 questions that I need to do dimension reduction on. About half the questions are ordinal (Likert-style questions), and the other half are qualitative/nominal. I've been given a suggestion to perform Multiple Correspondence Analysis on the dataset, but I was wondering, would it be methodologically sound to perform PCA based on a heterogeneous correlation matrix that contains polychoric and polyserial correlations (as produced by the hetcor() function in John Fox's 'polycor' R package). This makes sense to me, as PCA is basically a mathematical technique for calculating loadings and eigenvalues based on correlations.

Comment: If you mean that your matrix is partly one kind of correlation and partly another, then you are presenting a technique with a messy mixture, confident that the technique will sort it all out. Optimistic to a high degree!

Comment: Using a mixture approach Nick implies seems indeed questionnable, although some people use it. But your situation is different: part of your variables are _nominal_, for them tetrachoric correlation is unsuitable. Instead, use PCA with _optimal scaling_, a procedure known as Categorical PCA (acronymed often as CATPCA or PRINCALS). It combines both PCA and MCA in one. In SPSS, there is a good implementation of CATPCA. I believe R should be having it also.